# How to correct dotnet restore warning NU1604, does not contain an inclusive lower bound?

Tags: .net-core

While performing a `dotnet restore` on a .NET Core project (targeting .netcoreapp2.0.), I get the following warning:

> warning NU1604: Project dependency System.Net.NameResolution does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.

Here is the relevant line from the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Verison="4.3.0" />
```

(If you are wondering, I have included that reference to avoid a warning NU1605: Detected package downgrade.)

How does one "include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results"?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992843/213550 - maybe your project targets lower version of dotnet core/standard, which leads to NuGet warnings

Comment: Maybe useful to others: You can use `dotnet add reference <package|project>`. It should handle everything for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to indicate a minimum version for your package references you have to set the *Version* property of your reference to a range that contains an inclusive lower bound. As @Carter pointed out, [Microsoft provides a nice documentation about the format of that property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards).

If you don't specify an inclusive lower bound for your references, each restore will try to find a lower version of the package that can be used. More information about that warning can be found [on the nuget errors and warnings reference page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings#nu1604)

The only problem with your reference seems to be that you have a typo (*Verison* instead of *Version*). So the line should be

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3.0" />
```

With this line, you indicate that the project requires the version *4.3.0* or above of the package *System.Net.NameResolution*, hence the inclusive lower bound on *4.3.0*.

Comment: Yea the typo is the key.  There must not be a warning about it so make sure you are careful in correctly spelling the attribute names.

Comment: Well, Microsoft may provide a nice documentation. The problem is that they don't _link_ to the documentation from the error documentation! Which is why people have to come here. Personally, I thought that Version was _exact_, rather than a lower bound.

Answer (score 9):

I think the key there is to not include the last digit on your version.  Then it will set the lowerbound as 4.3.0 by default.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried both "4.3" and "4.3.*". The warning is the same.

Comment: That is odd from what I gather on this page that should give it a lower bound. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards
Quite a mystery!

Comment: @Carter you have a typo in your answer:  _Verison_  should read _Version_ , sadly it does not produce any warning on visual studio or msbuild. The original question had the same typo as well, and maybe that was causing the issue. Also, on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards), they say you can use _Patch_ number to indicate minimum version, *"This might be used to guarantee a dependency with a specific bug fix."*

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have my test project anymore to know if I was using the misspelling or not.  @Wally also misspelled it at least in the question which I am sure is where I copied it from.  No idea if it was corrected on projects.

Comment: @MuscicapaStriata Great catch. I had 'Verison" in my project file. Fixing that caused the warning to go away. If you submit an answer, I'll give you the points.

Comment: Ok. It was fine for me if @Carter just edited his answer, but I will now go ahead and provide my own.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, now I get this error:
detected package downgrade: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions from 2.1.1 to 2.1.0.

Comment: Try cleaning the solution and try to restore again. I've had that issue when intentionally trying to downgrade and if it detects a higher version installed it will reject what's in your dependencies list.

Answer (score 5):

Right click "Packages" -> Manage NuGet Packages -> Update

Update all broken packages, if that is not available remove them and add them again.

Answer (score 2):

Managing the package version is quite important. you must mention the version or have a floated version specified.

`<PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.3" />` or
`<PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution" Version="4.*" />`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249611/the-attribute-version-in-element-packagereference-is-unrecognized where the format is slightly different  --- <PackageReference Include="System.Net.NameResolution">
    <Version>4.3.0</Version>
</PackageReference>

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/Central-Package-Management) (and, especially if you are in the middle of switching over manually), check for typos/mangling in your `/Directory.Packages.props` e.g. the following happened in my case:

```
<Project>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageVersion Include="MinVer" Version="4.0.0" />

        <!-- EXAMPLE Copy/paste error: Version omitted -->
        <PackageVersion Include="FSharp.Core" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This lack-of-a-value propagates onto the `PackageReference` as if you had omitted or mis-spelt the `Version` attribute name as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error, but it was because I had updated the project from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.0 and the dependencies were incompatible. When I uninstalled and tried to reinstall the packages from the NuGet Package Manager, I got a new warning: `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson is not compatible with net5.0`. The original error gave no indication this was the case (although in hindsight, the package name did).

TL;DR: Check that your dependencies are compatible with the version of .NET you're using.