# Delete "obj" folder without side effects in "csproj"

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

Sometimes, when the nuget cache and intellisense *break* and neither `dotnet restore` nor `nuget restore` help, it's necessary to delete the `obj` folder in oder to *rebuild* the package information and fix all the false red flags.

In some projects, I cannot figure out when, after deleting `obj` (from inside VisualStudio) these elements are added to `csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <_UnmanagedRegistrationCache Remove="obj\MyProject.csproj.UnmanagedRegistration.cache" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ResolveComReferenceCache Remove="obj\Debug\MyProject.csproj.ResolveComReference.cache" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <IntermediateAssembly Remove="obj\Debug\MyProject.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_DebugSymbolsIntermediatePath Remove="obj\Debug\MyProject.pdb" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_DeploymentManifestEntryPoint Remove="obj\Debug\MyProject.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationManifest Remove="obj\Debug\Native.MyProject.manifest" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DeployManifest Remove="obj\Debug\MyProject.application" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I always remove them manually but it would be great if there was a way to prevent this from happening in the first place. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Looks like you've got some problem with Excluded Globs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#default-compilation-includes-in-net-core-projects

Comment: @JeremyThompson do you mean I somehow managed to do something to `msbuild` so that it doesn't automatically exclude `./obj` as it should (according to that link)?

Comment: It's a long article, but no I wasn't referring to the paragraph below on the way msbuild see's it, just the paragraph I anchor linked. If you run ProcMon and reproduce it, is it devenv.exe or the NuGet that overwrites the csproj file? Also when ever I have to delete the obj folder I also delete the bin folder and the .suo file, does deleting all 3 still cause the issue? Also you're not doing anything funky with NuGet - why does the cache break? Is there some type library problem possibly caused by a mismatch of DLL versions (in one or two of the NuGet dependencies)? Does a Clean Solution fix ?

Comment: @JeremyThompson the package cache usually breaks when I pull a new version from a repository that updated some packages. VS has difficulties in restoring them. It's constantly showing exclamation marks and doesn't recognize many types in code that come via packages. I haven't tried to delete any other files or folders. I'll do this next time and see how this works. csproj, however, is updated virtually instantly. I hit obj delete and at the same moment the csproj is populated with that trash.

Comment: I feel your pain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55565841/495455