# Microsoft.Identity.Web in ASP.NET Core 2.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Anyone managed to install Microsoft.Identity.Web and run on ASP.NET Core 2.1?

I've got quite a few ASP.NET Core 2.1 API projects as they have to refer to DLLs targeting .NET 4.7.2. The apps use Azure AD as authentication and I recently tried hours to upgrade to `Microsoft.Identity.Web` without success. It depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.* 5.0` or later. It causes Kestrel to throw an error right after startup:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.InplaceStringBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.DateTimeFormatter.ToRfc1123String(DateTimeOffset dateTime, Boolean quoted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.DateHeaderValueManager.SetDateValues(DateTimeOffset value)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer..ctor(IOptions`1 options, ITransportFactory transportFactory, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

It seems that a method [removed](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27986) when `Extentions.Primitive` became 5.0 that is required to run Kestrel. Any workaround?

Additional note (13/Oct/21):

As Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives has not been installed explicitly, it is not shown on the Nuget package list, therefor impossible to downgrade. If I try install older version such as 2.1.6 explicitly, it refuses with the error:

> NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives from 5.0.0 to 2.1.6. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> test21 -> Microsoft.Identity.Web 1.18.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 5.0.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives (>= 5.0.0)
> test21 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives (>= 2.1.6)

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade Microsoft.Extensions.primitives  to version less than 5 ex: 3.1 or 2.1 .Try uninstall and install again if direct version downgrade or upgrade doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. I've added note.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the package before installing the required version and rebuilding the project? If that was done ,Have you got to check and try any of [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605)  or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709533/detected-package-downgrade-warning-dotnet-core-vs-2017) ?

Comment: As stated I cannot uninstall or downgrade something doesn’t exist. If you have a working example, can you kindly share,  github or edit your answer to include csproj?

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the package from Version 5.0.0 to Version 2.1.0 through `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives` to solve the error.

By using NuGet Package Manager. You can select any available version of the package and update it.

If you use the NuGet manager (interface) in Visual Studio, you will be able to view package dependencies before installing or updating.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on an ASP.NET Core web api 2.1 . I had a similar
problem  when I tried with Microsoft identity. As you said
Microsoft.Identity.Web has a dependency on
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives on Version = 5.0.0. I was able to
solve the problem by downgrading that package from of
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives  Version 5.0.0 to Version 2.1.0 and
also by downgrading Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions
to 2.1.0 which it depends on but you may also try for other versions
,if the error doesn’t occur.Then you may try the same with microsoft
identity . When you do that save and close and start the application
again.

Other work arounds

- Sometimes if that doesn’t work , you may have missed adding that
  particular dependencies  in cs.proj file or may have missed adding packagereference similar to error .So please check that too.
- If not try deleting the bin /obj folder having those dependencies or
  just adding those dependencies or target frame works
- Or you can resolve the issue by executing update command in package
  manager console by

  Update-Package -reinstall -Project MyProject

Comment: Will this not cause problems or errors when running the application? Since Microsoft.Identity.Web, is dependant on 5.0.